# TYPO3 v9.5 no URL Segment [slug] field visible in Page Edit

Tags: typo3, url-routing, slug, typo3-9.x

After upgrading from Typo3v9 to v9.5, I still do not see the URL Segment [slug] field .

The field has been added to the "pages" table under the column/field "slug" and also been populated, but the field is not visible in the BE and the links not updated.

Is there documentation/configuration I am missing?

Comment: Documentation:
https://typo3.org/help/documentation/whats-new/
https://forge.typo3.org/attachments/download/33792/TYPO3-v9-LTS-whats-new.english.pdf
pg20.

I now know I have to first let Typo3 create the file:
typo3conf/sites/myOwnSiteName_siteconfig1/config.yaml

which I can then customise, edit and add code for extension like News.
The steps are not clearly explained sequentially.

So first do the page 20 part
and then you can have access to the Page 9 configurations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a **Site Configuration** for your page tree in the new *Sites* module of the TYPO3 backend.

Only then the new slug field becomes visible in backend forms and the URL segments get used in the frontend instead of the old default *index.php?id=1* links.

Comment: fantastic - that work - could not find that step in the documentation - just the editing once activated.